# Water Heater Replacement - Old unit with AC Lines?

Tags: water, heater, copper

Been a lurker for awhile but now need a bit of help.

Recently bought a house (Built 1992) with an original 20+ year old AO Smith short boy water heater. Still works, another win for AO Smith however the tank is rusting and leaking (See pictures).  AC compressor is dated 2001.

Time to replace, the old heater has 4 copper lines (hot & cold on top) plus 2 AC Lines im guessing on the bottom of the tank. The bottom pipes are not warm but are connected and seem to go to the upstairs - What do I do with these?

I am a big time DIY with a pretty good toolbox and skill but need a little direction.  Thank you in advance for any help / info.

The drain is right next to those pipes - sorry for the bad picture. Again DEF not the drain spout.

[image: Top lines]
[image: Bottom lines]

Comment: Can you remove some tape and shed light on the bottom connections? That looks like an extension on the drain valve to me, but I'm not sure why there would be two.

Comment: Model # on top pic ELJF-50. Specs [here](http://lakesidesupply.com/lakesidesupply/catalog/pdfs/ao_smith.pdf) agree the bottom should be drain.

Comment: Fixed to lurker lol!! thanks ... yes ill clean that up and show a cleaner pic - my bad.    The drain spigot is right next to the pipes. Def not the drain though

Comment: Could it be an lines that drain into the water heater???

Comment: Can you trace the insulated lines and see where they go?

Comment: Are you sure they don't go into the drain line? It was/is not uncommon for return lines on a thermo-siphon recirculating system to tie into the drain port.